# Spring-boot populate H2 database with schema.sql and data.sql

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-jdbc

I set up Spring-boot to work with H2 in-memory database
`application.properties` file is in the `/config` directory
and it looks like, this file is processed

```ini
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.path=/myconsole
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.schema=schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=data.sql
```

This file is processed and the console appears at `/myconsole`
But the `schema.sql` and `data.sql` are not processed and db is empty.
I placed `schema.sql` and `data.sql` files both under `/config` and `/src/main/resources`.

SQL language instructions are correct and I can populate the table using console input.

Another strange thing is
even though i name db as

```ini
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
```

the spring console loads another database `testdb`

```
o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory --- Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

How to load the H2 database correctly?

Answer (score 11):

Resolved the issue.

The spring boot app requires its ownd jdbc dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

NON-boot dependency, that I had, is NOT enough alone:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Without the "spring-boot-starter-jdbc" dependency
"spring.datasource.url" settings in file "application.properties"
are not processed.
That file is actually processed, but not the jdbc settings.
Spring boot will create its own testdb in the memory, which destroys the data
after closing the application.